# Regular Expression Matching More Than Expected

Tags: php, regex

I have a large chunk of HTML.

With this:

```
~<div>(?:.*?)<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s"\']+(#_ftnref([0-9]+))["\']+.*?>(?:[^<]+|.*?)?</a>(.*?)</div>~si
```

I am capturing this:

```
<div> </div><hr align="left" size="1" width="33%" /><div><p><a title="" href="#_ftnref1">[1]</a> This is not to suggest that there are only two possible arguments to be made in support of  blah blah <em>blah</em>.</p></div>
```

But! I want this:

```
<div><p><a title="" href="#_ftnref1">[1]</a> This is not to suggest that there are only two possible arguments to be made in support of  blah blah <em>blah</em>.</p></div>
```

Can you help?

PS:  `(?: )`, in contrast to `( )`, is used to avoid capturing text. I'm doing that on purpose because I want the returned $matches array to be consistent for several different regex not mentioned in this post.

Comment: Would you mind using `DOM` to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php

Comment: Yes, I would mind. DOM is not appropriate because sometimes the markup is garbage.

Comment: Mario, that worked! Please answer the question and I will give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lazy matching with `.*?` doesn't work, you need to come up with some exclusion pattern.

```
(?:(?!</div>).)*
```

Would for instance only match one `div` and stop/skip after any contained `</div>`

Alternatively a length constraint could be a workaround:

```
(?:.{0,20})
```